# Нужна помощь с flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, layout

Прошу помочь решить такую задачу с помощь flexbox.

Есть такая разметка:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  max-width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fluid-left"></div>
  <div class="content">Какой-то контент</div>
  <div class="fluid-right"></div>
</div>
```

Если браузер меньше максимальной ширины content, то ширина у fluid-left и fluid-right нулевая. Если браузер шире чем максимальной ширины content, остальное место равномерно заполняют fluid-left и fluid-right по бока.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bveq10kv/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скрытие делается через **Media Query**.

Заполнение оставшийся ширины через  `flex-grow: 1;`.

https://jsfiddle.net/bveq10kv/1/

```css
.container
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content
{
  max-width: 800px;  
}

.fluid-left
{
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.fluid-right
{
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.content
{
  background-color: yellow;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .fluid-right,.fluid-left  {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="fluid-left"></div>
    <div class="content">Какой-то контент</div>
    <div class="fluid-right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: возможно лучше использовать `flex: 1` вместо `flex-grow: 1`

Comment: @diraria как я понимаю это одно и тоже

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Кстати работает как надо даже без медиа-запросов.

Comment: @Budimir а вы в бока контент поместите и проверьте без медиа запросов. Хотя если вам там контент вообще не нужен, думаю может и без них работать. Просто контент может не дать схлопнутся.